# Get the mean of numerical columns in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: pandas, mean, multi-index

I want to calculate the mean of numerical columns in a multi-index dataframe, and append the dataframe with the new results as a new row.

```py
        subject  1                  subject  2                  subject  3…
Country Unite   2017    2018    Frq 2017 Score  2018 Score  2017    2018    Frq 2017 Score  2018 Score  
Argentina   K   12  22  100 50.77214238 51.54316539 12  22  100 50.77214238 51.54316539 
Australia   K   68  13  150 66.92805676 67.60645268 68  13  150 66.92805676 67.60645268 
Mean            40  17.5    125 58.85009957 59.57480904 40  17.5    125 58.85009957 59.57480904
```

I'v tried using this line, But I get a new row full with nan

```py
G20.loc['mean'] = G20.mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True)
```

[Exmple of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c22jL.png)

Thanks

Comment: what's the expected outcome?

Comment: @MarkWang A new row that continues the mean of each column.
```
mean 68      13      150   66.  67.    68   13     150 66.  67.
```

Comment: Isn't this the row corresponding to Australia? I recommend you provide the input and output clearly in the question.

Comment: @MarkWang Thanks for your patience, I've realised that the description wasn't enough. I added more details and a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.random.seed(43)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(6,6)), columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Top A','Top B'],['W','X','Y']]))
df.loc['Mean',:] = df.mean()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Top A                    Top B                    
         W         X    Y         W         X         Y
0      6.0  3.000000  7.0  4.000000  6.000000  9.000000
1      2.0  6.000000  7.0  4.000000  3.000000  7.000000
2      7.0  2.000000  5.0  4.000000  1.000000  7.000000
3      5.0  1.000000  4.0  0.000000  9.000000  5.000000
4      8.0  0.000000  9.0  2.000000  6.000000  3.000000
5      8.0  2.000000  4.0  2.000000  6.000000  4.000000
Mean   6.0  2.333333  6.0  2.666667  5.166667  5.833333
```

Comment: I get a new row (index=Mean) with nan values. And df.mean() return an empty series. 

Series([], dtype: float64).

Comment: Do you have NaN's in your data?   Can you add data in this question that will reproduce this result?